# Finite normal subgroups of $SO(4)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, orthogonality, normal-subgroups, quotient-spaces

What are the finite normal subgroups of $SO(4)$?  If these do not exist (or if they are trivial, e.g. from some projection to $SO(2)$), are there different finite normal subgroups of $O(4),$ $U(4)$, or $SU(4)$?

[Many thanks to the StackExchange community for their help the last week or two as I piece together my understanding of a tough technical problem!]

Comment: It's not clear if you are lumping several questions together here.  A trivial normal subgroup would conventionally mean the identity subgroup or perhaps the group itself.  There is a website that provides fairly comprehensive information about small groups and their properties.  Is a citation to information like that for $SO(4)$ enough?

Comment: I'm hoping to find subgroups other than the identity and the group itself :-)

Is SO(4) considered a small group?  It's infinite!

I don't think this is lumped -- I'm just seeking a simple enumeration of finite normal subgroups of SO(4) -- or of a larger group, if such a thing doesn't exist.  The Wikipedia page for SO(4) mentions that SO(4) isn't a simple group (so it does have normal subgroups), but the discussion is quite technical and hard to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The group $SO(4) = SO(4,\mathbb{R})$ does have a nontrivial finite normal subgroup of $\{\pm I \}$, and this in common with all even dimensions, because $\det(-I) = 1$.  Geometrically this is reflection through the origin, and [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotations_in_4-dimensional_Euclidean_space) calls this *central inversion*. [Note that much of the technical content of this article seems to have been contributed [by J.E. Mebius](http://jemebius.home.xs4all.nl/so4-wiki.pdf).]

The subgroup $\{\pm I \}$ is the centre of $SO(4)$, as it is in all even dimensions.

Unlike the higher even dimensions, $SO(4)$ has a couple of additional normal subgroups, although these are not finite.  They are described in the article as the left-isoclinic rotations $S_L^3$ and the right-isoclinic rotations $S_R^3$.  Each is isomorphic to the [unit quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion#Unit_quaternion) $S^3$.

Comment: Got it!  Thanks.  Too bad there aren't any more interesting finite subgroups -- would have been useful for my research :-)

Comment: There are interesting finite subgroups, but not normal ones.  I can add more references if you like.

Comment: Sadly I need to find a quotient group -- was there was a finite normal subgroup that looked like (contained?) the hyperoctahedral group.  Alas!  Thanks for your help, though.  Related to this question:  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/215407/parameterizing-rotations-of-a-cube -- slowly working through a tricky computational problem

Comment: The other question suggests you want to parameterize $SO(3)$ in a way that rotates the cube.  Are you now trying to parameterize  $SO(4)$ ?

Comment: Well, I'm trying to find some group that has $SO(3)$ as a subgroup and can be quotiented by symmetries of a cube -- but it may be the case such a thing doesn't exist.  Totally stuck on how to pose a problem in geometry but it may simply be the case that what I'm trying to do is ill-posed!

Comment: This would be great, if you have some time to help out!  I need some mathematical collaborators to help me tackle this stuff -- any and all help is welcome.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27354/discussion-between-justin-solomon-and-hardmath).

Comment: [oops, that last one happened automatically, but I am happy to chat about this!  Or, can provide more info via email.]

Comment: I posted in the chat room (and deleted my suggestion in the comment chain above).